# Decision boundary in perceptron not correct

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, perceptron

I was preparing some code for a lecture and re-implemented a simple perceptron: 2 inputs and 1 output. Aim: a linear classifier.

Here's the code that creates the data, setups the perceptron and trains it:

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Two randoms clouds
x = [(1,3)]*10+[(3,1)]*10
x = np.asarray([(i+np.random.rand(), j+np.random.rand()) for i,j in x])

# Colors
cs = "m"*10+"b"*10
# classes
y = [0]*10+[1]*10



class Perceptron:
    def __init__(self):
        self.w = np.random.randn(3)
        self.lr = 0.01

    def train(self, x, y, verbose=False):
        errs = 0.

        for xi, yi in zip(x,y):
            x_ = np.insert(xi, 0, 1)
            r = self.w @ x_

            ######## HERE IS THE MAGIC HAPPENING #####
            r = r >= 0
            ##########################################

            err = float(yi)-float(r)

            errs += np.abs(err)

            if verbose:
                print(yi, r)

            self.w = self.w + self.lr * err * x_

        return errs

    def predict(self, x):
        return np.round(self.w @ np.insert(x, 0, 1, 1).T)

    def decisionLine(self):
        w = self.w
        slope =  -(w[0]/w[2]) / (w[0]/w[1])
        intercept = -w[0]/w[2]
        return slope, intercept

p = Perceptron()

line_properties = []
errs = []

for i in range(20):
    errs.append(p.train(x, y, True if i == 999 else False))
    line_properties.append(p.decisionLine())

print(p.predict(x)) # works like a charm!



@interact
def showLine(i:(0,len(line_properties)-1,1)=0):
    xs = np.linspace(1, 4)
    a, b = line_properties[i]

    ys = a * xs + b

    plt.scatter(*x.T)
    plt.plot(xs, ys, "k--")
```

At the end, I am calculating the decision boundary, i.e. the linear eq. separating class 0 and 1. However, it seems to be off. I tried inversion etc but have no clue what is wrong. Interestingly, if I change the learning rule to

```
self.w = self.w + self.lr * err / x_
```

i.e. dividing by `x_`, it works properly - I am totally confused. Anyone an idea?

### Solved for real

Now I added one small, but very important part to the Perceptron that I just forgot (and maybe others may forget it as well). You have to do the thresholded activation! `r = r >= 0` - and now it is centered on **0** and then it does work - this is basically the answer below. If you don't do this, you **have to change the classes** to get again the center at **0**. Currently, I prefer having the classes -1 and 1 as this gives a better decision line (centered) instead of a line that is very close to one of the data clouds.

Before:

[image]

Now:

[image]

Comment: The error nicely converges btw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a linear regression (not logistic regression!) with targets 0 and 1.  And the line you plot is the line where the model predicts 0, so it *should* ideally cut through the cloud of points labeled 0, as in your first plot.

If you don't want to implement the sigmoid for logistic regression, then at least you will want to display a boundary line that corresponds to a value of 0.5 rather than 0.

As for inverting the weights providing a plot that looks like what you want, I think that's just a coincidence of this data.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I tested it with class -1 and +1 (assuming the center line is at 0) and here you go, the line is EXACTLY where it should be. But I am not sure if the reasoning is correct; perceptrons are per se [linear classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron), no?

Comment: It just comes down to the details of the update rule and decision boundary depending on the format of the data.  You can use targets `-1, 1` as you say, or you can modify the rules a little for targets `0, 1`.

Comment: Thanks Ben, with your help I found my logical mistake, I was not using the activation (see answer above) so it is actually 0 centered, also with the ```[0, 1]``` class. And then it works as expected. Simple thing, but important. The same centering happens with the changed classes, as you mentioned. It was really helpful!